# Struggling with gesture dragging

Tags: android

I am trying to implement dragging in my Android app. I am following the Android documentation sample listed [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale). Here is the code:

```
// The current viewport. This rectangle represents the currently visible
// chart domain and range.
private RectF mCurrentViewport =
        new RectF(AXIS_X_MIN, AXIS_Y_MIN, AXIS_X_MAX, AXIS_Y_MAX);

// The current destination rectangle (in pixel coordinates) into which the
// chart data should be drawn.
private Rect mContentRect;

private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener
            = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
...

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    // Scrolling uses math based on the viewport (as opposed to math using pixels).

    // Pixel offset is the offset in screen pixels, while viewport offset is the
    // offset within the current viewport.
    float viewportOffsetX = distanceX * mCurrentViewport.width()
            / mContentRect.width();
    float viewportOffsetY = -distanceY * mCurrentViewport.height()
            / mContentRect.height();
    ...
    // Updates the viewport, refreshes the display.
    setViewportBottomLeft(
            mCurrentViewport.left + viewportOffsetX,
            mCurrentViewport.bottom + viewportOffsetY);
    ...
    return true;
}
```

After the onScroll method executes, how do I update my View? Only the mCurrentViewport variable is updated in the sample.

Comment: can you explain what you want to do in your app? you want to drag a view from one point to another point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite some code going into using those Android tutorials that is not mentioned there. I suggest using the import sample from menu from Android Studio. This one is possibly what you need to play with:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicGestureDetect/

I have embedded that Android Tutorial code below in BasicGestureDetectFragment.java if you use the guthyb code above. In "moveLog" method you can do whathever you like with the dx values. I have also put a code under this that shows you how to creat an app dragging a picture. Just add "ic_launcher.png" to image folder under res folder so that you can have an image and move it. I suggest coding with Corona SDK that is a lot simpler than Android.

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package com.example.android.basicgesturedetect;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;
import com.example.android.common.logger.LogFragment;

import static android.view.MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;

public class BasicGestureDetectFragment extends Fragment{
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View gestureView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sample_output);

        gestureView.setFocusable(true);

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(init_detector)

        // First create the GestureListener that will include all our callbacks.
        // Then create the GestureDetector, which takes that listener as an argument.
        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureListener();
        final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), gestureListener);

        /* For the view where gestures will occur, create an onTouchListener that sends
         * all motion events to the gesture detector.  When the gesture detector
         * actually detects an event, it will use the callbacks you created in the
         * SimpleOnGestureListener to alert your application.
        */


        gestureView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float mLastTouchX;
            float mLastTouchY;
            float mPosX;
            float mPosY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                gd.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

                //**********
                final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent);
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(motionEvent);
                        final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(motionEvent, pointerIndex);
                        final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(motionEvent, pointerIndex);

                        // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                        mLastTouchX = x;
                        mLastTouchY = y;
                        // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motionEvent, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                        final int pointerIndex =
                                MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(motionEvent, mActivePointerId);

                        final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(motionEvent, pointerIndex);
                        final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(motionEvent, pointerIndex);

                        // Calculate the distance moved
                        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                        mPosX += dx;
                        mPosY += dy;
                        moveLog(dx);

                        //invalidate();

                        // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                        mLastTouchX = x;
                        mLastTouchY = y;

                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

                        final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(motionEvent);
                        final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motionEvent, pointerIndex);

                        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                            mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(motionEvent, newPointerIndex);
                            mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(motionEvent, newPointerIndex);
                            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motionEvent, newPointerIndex);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //**********
                return false;
            }
        });
        // END_INCLUDE(init_detector)
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sample_action) {
            clearLog();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clearLog() {
        LogFragment logFragment =  ((LogFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment));
        logFragment.getLogView().setText("");
    }
    public void moveLog(float x) {
        //do whatever you like
    }
}
```

- Image Drag App

Just start a blank app under Android Studio:
1 - Change activity_main.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java to this. 
(Leave the package name as your own: package com.jorc.move.myapplication;)

```
package com.jorc.move.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewGroup mainLayout;
    private ImageView image;

    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener());
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                                view.getLayoutParams();

                        xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                        yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "thanks for new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                mainLayout.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at the sample android-BasicGestureDetect, however, touch event simply gets logged. There is no indication of how to update a View that is being dragged.

Comment: Do you want just to drag an object on the screen?

Comment: I want to drag a photo inside an ImageView.

Comment: photo from where?

Comment: I do not have code for the photo yet. I am trying to figure out how to write the code that will pan the photo. If it would help I plan to decode the photo from the file system and use an ImageView to display the photo.

Comment: The way I setup the photo is already there under res folder. There is plenty of examples n github how to import photo by browsing your phone. I suggest always get one working example from github and run and test the app. Then use the code and classes in your main app. This way you learn about activity, context etc although takes longer but all parts will work and you learn more. For example, I get a github app how to send sms and one how to use accelerometer and then try to mix them to send sms bu shaking mobile which comes from accelerometer data.